# Why does calling calloc in gdb not appear to zero out the memory?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm doing some experimentation with editing a process memory while it's running, and I noticed when I call `calloc` in a gdb'd process, the call seems to work and return the original passed pointer, but the memory does not appear to be initialized to `0`:

```
(gdb) call calloc(1, 32)
$88 = (void *) 0x8d9d50
(gdb) x/8xw 0x8d9d50
0x8d9d50:       0xf74a87d8      0x00007fff      0xf74a87d8      0x00007fff
0x8d9d60:       0xfbfbfbfb      0xfbfbfbfb      0x00000000      0x9b510000
```

If I call `memset` on the resulting pointer, however, the initialization works just fine:

```
(gdb) call memset(0x8d9d50, 0, 32)
$89 = 9280848
(gdb) x/8xw 0x8d9d50
0x8d9d50:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x8d9d60:       0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting question. The answer is: on Linux (where I assume you ran your program) this:

```
(gdb) call calloc(1, 32)
```

doesn't call `calloc` from `libc.so.6`.

Rather it calls `calloc` from `ld-linux.so.2`. And *that* `calloc` is very minimal. It expects to be called only from `ld-linux.so.2` itself, and it assumes that whatever pages it has access to are "clean" and [do not require](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-minimal.c;h=6034b5a3fa601299d94da88c6c821d707c10b063;hb=HEAD#l103) a `memset`. (That said, I could not reproduce the unclean `calloc` using glibc-2.19).

You can confirm this like so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  void *p = calloc(1, 10);
  return p == 0;
}

gcc -g foo.c -m32 && gdb -q ./a.out

Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x8048426: file foo.c, line 4.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:4
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
4         void *p = calloc(1, 10);
(gdb) b __libc_calloc
Breakpoint 2 at 0xf7e845a0
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, 0xf7e845a0 in calloc () from /lib32/libc.so.6
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  0xf7e845a0 in calloc () from /lib32/libc.so.6
0x0804843a in main () at foo.c:4
4         void *p = calloc(1, 10);
```

Note how the call from the program to `calloc` hit breakpoint #2.

```
(gdb) n
5         return p == 0;
(gdb) call calloc(1,32)
$1 = 134524952
```

Note that above call from GDB did *not* hit breakpoint #2.

Let's try again with:

```
(gdb) info func calloc
All functions matching regular expression "calloc":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x08048310  calloc@plt
0xf7fdc820  calloc@plt
0xf7ff16a0  calloc
0xf7e25450  calloc@plt
0xf7e845a0  __libc_calloc
0xf7e845a0  calloc

(gdb) info sym 0xf7ff16a0
calloc in section .text of /lib/ld-linux.so.2    ## this is the wrong one!

(gdb) break *0xf7ff16a0
Breakpoint 3, 0xf7ff16a0 in calloc () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2

(gdb) disable    
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 7 at 0x8048426: file foo.c, line 4.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 7, main () at foo.c:4
4         void *p = calloc(1, 10);
(gdb) ena 3
(gdb) n
5         return p == 0;
```

Note that breakpoint #3 did *not* fire above (because the "real" `__libc_calloc` was called).

```
(gdb) call calloc(1,32)

Breakpoint 3, 0xf7ff16a0 in calloc () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(calloc) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7ff16a0 in calloc () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#1  <function called from gdb>
#2  main () at foo.c:5
```

QED.

**Update:**

> I don't see the ld-linux version in the output of "info func calloc"

I think what you see in `info func` depends on whether you have debug symbols installed. For a (64-bit) glibc *with* debug symbols, here is what I see:

```
(gdb) info func calloc
All functions matching regular expression "calloc":

File dl-minimal.c:
void *calloc(size_t, size_t);         <<< this is the wrong one!

File malloc.c:
void *__libc_calloc(size_t, size_t);  <<< this is the one you want!

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000400440  calloc@plt
0x00007ffff7ddaab0  calloc@plt
0x00007ffff7a344e0  calloc@plt
```

Here is another way to figure out what `calloc` GDB thinks it should be calling:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x8048426: file foo.c, line 4.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:4
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
4     void *p = calloc(1, 10);
(gdb) p &calloc
$1 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0xf7ff16a0 <calloc>
(gdb) info sym 0xf7ff16a0
calloc in section .text of /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Or, for completness, using 64-bit glibc with debug symbols:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400555: file foo.c, line 4.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:4
4     void *p = calloc(1, 10);
(gdb) p &calloc
$1 = (void *(*)(size_t, size_t)) 0x7ffff7df1bc0 <calloc>
(gdb) info sym 0x7ffff7df1bc0
calloc in section .text of /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: Though the explanation makes sense, I don't see the ld-linux version in the output of "info func calloc".  I've tried putting breakpoints on everything it does list there, but the call within gdb still doesn't hit any of them.

Comment: Amazing!  Accepting the answer now.

Comment: I've just had a fight with this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/debugging-dlopen-4175668676/ I wish I've found this earlier;) Well done and thank you very much.